# Dragging an object in openGL

Tags: python, opengl, drag, glut

What I'm trying to do is drag the end of a line across the screen using a motion function like so:

```
def motion(a, b):
b=wh-b
global MOVING

if (MOVING == 1):
    table[0].x=a
    table[0].y=b
    display()
    drawObjects()
```

Right now, my line objects are stored in a list called table, and are redrawn using the function drawObjects. Whenever I call display, everything on the screen is removed. Right now I have the motion function called using

```
glutMotionFunc(motion)
```

What I'm trying to do is have the line always be visible when it is being dragged by the mouse. However, whenever I try to drag a line, it disappears and only reappers after I have dragged the mouse. Is there a way to have the line always be visible while it is being dragged across the screen?

Comment: Use double buffering to see if that effect goes away.

Comment: Adding glFlush() at the end seemed to fix this.

Comment: You mean to tell me your display function didn't already end in glFlush()?